# docX ReplaceText works incorrect

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a template:

```
1.  Q1
 a. Q1a
 b. Q1b
 c. Q1c
 d. Q1d
```

.
.
.

```
  2.     Q10
    a.  Q10a
    b.  Q10b
    c.  Q10c
    d.  Q10d
```

I want to replace Q1-Q10 with some data. I use DocX library.

```
  for (int q = 0; q < 20; q++)
        {
            docX.ReplaceText(String.Format("Q{0}", q+1), questions1[q].Text, false, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
            docX.ReplaceText(String.Format("Q{0}a", q+1), questions1[q].AnswerA, false, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
            docX.ReplaceText(String.Format("Q{0}b", q+1), questions1[q].AnswerB, false, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
            docX.ReplaceText(String.Format("Q{0}c", q+1), questions1[q].AnswerC, false, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
            docX.ReplaceText(String.Format("Q{0}d", q+1), questions1[q].AnswerD, false, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
        }
```

So output should be for questions more then 9:

```
     2.  This is 10 question
     a. This is 10a question
     b. This is 10b question
     c. This is 10c question
     d. This is 10d question
```

But it is like:
So output should be for questions more then 9:

```
     2.  This is 1 question0
      a.    This is 1a question0
      b.    This is 1b question0
      c.    This is 1c question0
      d.    This is 1d question0
```

So I assume that ReplaceText(src, dst) searches for blocks that contains src and immidiatelly replaces with dst. How to make it search the EXACT value.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link to the library you are using and that your question relates to.

Comment: Replace text is doing exactly what you're telling it to do. If you replace all instances of `Q1` in the string `Q1, Q15a` with `Test` you get  `Test, Test5a`. String replacement is probably a bad choice for this.  Is there some reason you can't use mail merge fields?

Comment: https://docx.codeplex.com/ @stuartd

Comment: @theB I have a large document with Q1 ... as a template, so I need to insert data instead of each Qn.

Comment: A replace method should at least count the number of characters for replacement and replace only if this number is equal to found ones. It must be an option for that.

Answer (score 1):

So This DocX library is not working fine fo this task, so I used this code:

```
private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doc, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        //options
        object matchCase = false;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object matchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;
        //execute find and replace
        doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
            ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
    }
```

object matchWholeWord = true; //this row is crutial